# Join specific items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to `join` the items in a string array that contain values and keep the empty items.

```js
// example array
const sentenceSplit = ["There", "is", "a", "", "", "cat", "in", "", "three"];
```

For the above example, I would like to achieve the following outcome:

```js
["There is a", "", "", "cat in", "", "three"]
```

I tried using `reduce`, but couldn't figure out the solution.

```js
const result = sentenceSplit.reduce((acc, val) => {
  // can't figure out logic
});
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: @adiga I don't have any code to show you, I'm sorry

Comment: Please read the [tour]: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and check whether the last produced entry or the current string is empty. If so, the current string should be a separate entry, otherwise it should be concatenated to the previous entry:

```js
const sentenceSplit = ["There", "is", "a", "", "", "cat", "in", "", "three"];

let result = sentenceSplit.reduce((acc, str) => {
    if (str && acc[acc.length-1]) {
        acc[acc.length-1] += " " + str;
    } else {
        acc.push(str);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```